# raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp) smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, smtp

I'm trying to make a program to send me quotes via gmail.com at a specific time in windows. But I get an error:

> raise SMTPAuthenticationError(code, resp)
> smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials y18-20020a2e9792000000b002c50233a2f5sm56354lji.52 - gsmtp')

Can you explain why this error occuring?

Comment: Yes, it explains it on the second line, Username and Password not accepted

Answer (score 0):

This occures for the authenticate you password you should go to your gmail and make a 2-step  verifiying then in your code you shoulh change your password to this